# Is magento http/https secure or should the entire website be forced to use https?

Tags: magento-1.9, security, cookie, https

I'm setting up a magento website but one thing i've noticed is https can be used only for secure content such as login pages and account details etc.

This means on product pages regular http is used.

Doesn't this mean the cookie transmitted over http is vulnerable to be stolen by any cookie sniffing program?

Or does Magento handle these pages by not sending a cookie and getting the default page and then using a local cookie to change the header to contain the custom name and profile picture etc.

Answer (score 6):

`https` is only required on pages that submit data like the checkout page for example. Still, using a https URL for unsecure base url wouldn't hurt

If you're worrying about people stealing cookies (session hijacking) go to `System > Configuration > Web > Session Validation Settings` and enable `Validate REMOTE_ADDR`

[EDIT] - Credits to @AnnaVölkl

- so if you transfer the cookie both via HTTP and HTTPS, it's pretty easy to steal
- if you set the cookie to HTTPS only (the standard PHP setcookie method has the $secure flag, you will loose the session when switching from http to https. but it's safe of course.

***Use HTTP Only***
Determines if Magento Cookies can be used only over an unsecure channel (http), or can also be used over an encrypted channel (https). Options include: Yes / No

there's no reason to not use https accross the whole website any more:
[https://istlsfastyet.com](https://istlsfastyet.com/)

Comment: Thank for the response, could you explain what this does?

Comment: It checks if the session ID in the cookie matches a stored session + the users IP address that was stored with this session. So for me to steal your cookie value wouldn't work without also having your IP

Comment: So this would protect against cookie theft across networks but not on a public one. Is there any way to prevent this on a public network without full https across the site

Comment: I think you're right but I'm not sure. I've asked someone else to help me out :)

Comment: @Gareth I've updated the answer with help from Anna :)

Comment: `HTTPS` globally is critical. If you allow any HTTP at all then a MITM can inject JS that can prevent the transition to HTTPS, or redirect to a different HTTPS url where sensitive information can be phished.

Comment: Use HTTP Only is not a reference to HTTPS. Http-Only cookies are not accessible to the browser and they cannot therefore be stolen by XSS. There is a Secure flag on cookies that deal with HTTPS however.